# how to do OR to all the words in full text search instead of AND in postgres

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a `post` table which has a `tsv` column. Let's assume `tsv` is generated by title only. There are 3 rows in the `post` table now. Their titles are 'hello', 'world' and 'hello world'.

When I do a `select` query like

```
SELECT p.*
   FROM plainto_tsquery('hElLo WoRlD’) AS q,
        post p
   WHERE tsv @@ q
ORDER BY ts_rank_cd(p.tsv, plainto_tsquery('hElLo WoRlD')) DESC;
```

I would assume all three records returned with the one has 'hello world' as title being the first in the list, but the query actually only return one record. How can I have all 3 records return? and of course sorted by most relevant.

tsv is generated by `setweight(to_tsvector(coalesce(new.title,'')), 'A');`

and if there's a way to do both would be even better. Like what google can do `"hello world" foo bar` will return results with "hello world" and/or foo and/or bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the "or" operator in `tsquery`:

```
... WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('hello | world');
```

Comment: i was studying the difference between `to_tsquery` and `plainto_tsquery` but didn't really understand. it seems like using `to_tsquery` would solve the problem! thanks

Comment: `plainto_tsquery` will insert ANDs. For something more advanced like OR, you need `to_tsquery`.